# Pentatonic, hexatonic, heptatonic, octatonic... what is a 12 tone scale called?

Tags: scales, terminology

Pentatonic, hexatonic, heptatonic, octatonic... what is a 12 tone scale called?

This seems like a dumb question. I know it's just called the *chromatic scale*, but   isn't there a ______-tonic name?

I thought maybe *dodeca-tonic*. *Dodecaphonic* means something else, 12-tone composition.

I see some Google results for either *dodecaphonic scale* or *duodecatonic scale*. The latter points to a lot of Chinese mysticism pages.

Is there a generally accepted term?

Comment: What's wrong with dodecatonic? if you're going to go Greek, that is the word. Wikipedia uses the term in several articles, but the links point to the "chromatic scale" page, so they consider it a synonym.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it necessarily, But that chromatic scale page doesn't actually use the term. The pages pointing to it do. That kind of spotty usage is what makes me unsure, so I thought I would ask the Music Practice & Theory mind hive.

Comment: I think the reason that that term is so uncommon compared to, say, hexatonic or octatonic, is that every dodecatonic scale in 12-TET EDO **is** the chromatic scale.

Comment: Chromatic means non-diatonic, so I see *chromatic scale* in itself as a misnomer! Some of its notes will be diatonic, surely? 'Dodecatonic' seems to be apposite. And, just like scientists and mathematicians, we need big words that have exact meanings... Just like '12 tone scale'?

Comment: I’ve only seen “dodecatonic” used with any regularity.

Comment: Is it just as an academic exercise? Or have you actually managed to dream up some music using a 12-tone scale that does not sound like it is a chromatic scale? I think it would be rather hard! Also because scale is a somewhat unrefined term in comparison to related concepts like rag and maqam which can contain more information.

Comment: @Chai, neither, I just want to know if a particular term was commonly used. But there is plenty of "chromatic" music, late 19th century and 12-tone espeically. No one would be dreaming up something new to use the chromatic scale.

Comment: @Tim, that's part of my reason for this question. Chromatic is sort of a general term, or as you point out means 'non-diatonic'. If there are all the other numeric classes of scales, why not for 12?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis as requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "Dodecatonic" is most commonly used to describe a 12-tone scale. This naming is consistent with "dodecagon" (a 12-sided figure) as well as a "dodecahedron" (a 12-faced three dimensional shape).

Answer (score 5):

Dodecatonic would seem to fit, but since we can already refer to it as the chromatic scale, there seems little point.

Comment: For non-12-EDO tunings/scales, can chromatic refer to the whole set of notes? E.g. every single note in 19-EDO.

Comment: Good question, but I suspect that 100 out 100 musicians would interpret chromatic scale as meaning all 12 piano notes.

Answer (score 3):

You seem a bit unclear with the Greek language.

**Dodecaphonic** comes from the Greek words *Δώδεκα* (dodeca = twelve) and *φώνος* (phonos = [phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics))* *as in phonetics*, not as in telephone)

**Dodecatonic** comes from the Greek words *Δώδεκα* (as above) and *τόνος* (tonos = tone)

> Dodecaphonic means something else, 12-tone composition.

Yes, but not necessarily. As you see above, I explained what it means exactly. When people refer to the 12-tone composition, they usually use words such as twelve-tone **serialism**, twelve-note **composition**, twelve-tone **technique** etc. You can take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-tone_technique) to see some other names as well.

But the difference between the 12-tone serialism and the 12-note scale is that, the scale is an ascending (and then descending) collection of pitches, whereas serialism is not necessarily in an ascending (or descending) order.

So basically, if you want to call the 12 note equal tempered scale anything else besides *chromatic*, either of these words are linguistically correct. For most people though, the term *chromatic scale* would be the most commonly known.

But if you wanna go a different way, as in penta**tonic**, hexa**tonic** etc, you can choose *dodecatonic*, so as to be consistent.

Not exactly thought in a scale per se, Nicolas Slonimsky in his book *Thesaurus of Scales and Melodic Patterns*, calls the division of the octave in twelve equal parts a **Semitone Progression**.

<sub>*a phone is any distinct speech sound or gesture, as per the Wikipedia article.</sub>

Comment: How is the "phon" in telephone and phonetics different? Googling the etymology suggests that phonos comes from Greek.